# Can anyone here describe me this higher order function written in python ? Specifically fn(fn(arg))

Tags: python, python-3.x, higher-order-functions

```py
def mult_by_five(x):
    
    return 5 * x

def call(fn, arg):
    
    """Call fn on arg"""
    return fn(arg)

def squared_call(fn, arg):
    
    """Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"""
    return **fn(fn(arg))**

print(

    call(mult_by_five, 1),
    squared_call(mult_by_five, 1), 
    sep='\n', # '\n' is the newline character - it starts a new line
)
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? what don't you understand?

Comment: What is it that you are asking *exactly*? The function seems pretty straightforward, and the docstring even states plainly: "Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"

Comment: Like you understand if I have a function, say `func`, then I can *call the function*, with some argument, e.g `func(42)`. I can call *another* function on the result of that, `other_func(func(42))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So the interesting one is this function.

```py
def squared_call(fn, arg):
    
    """Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"""
    return fn(fn(arg))
```

Basically it could be written as

```py
def squared_call(fn, arg):
    
    """Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"""
    first_call_result = fn(arg)  # call fn once on arg
    second_call_result = fn(first_call_result)  # call fn on result of first call
    return second_call_result
```

Which is just a more explicit version documented in the docstring.

In your case:

1. `first_call_result = fn(arg)` is 1*5 which is 5
2. `second_call_result = fn(first_call_result)` is 5*5 which is 25